# Unable to submit more than one bid in Car Auction Demo application using rest APIs but I am able to submit multiple bids using composer playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

REST Response :

```
{
"error": {
"statusCode": 500,
"name": "Error",
"message": "error trying invoke chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: Invalid or missing identifier for Type Offer in namespace org.acme.vehicle.auction)",
"stack": "Error: error trying invoke chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: Invalid or missing identifier for Type Offer in namespace org.acme.vehicle.auction)\n at _initializeChannel.then.then.then.then.catch (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:806:34)"
}
}
```

Console Response:

```
Unhandled error for request POST /api/VehicleListing: Error: Invalid or missing identifier for Type Offer in namespace org.acme.vehicle.auction
at Factory.newResource (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/factory.js:77:19)
at JSONPopulator.convertItem (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:142:50)
at JSONPopulator.visitField (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:104:34)
at JSONPopulator.visit (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:60:25)
at Field.accept (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/introspect/property.js:48:24)
at JSONPopulator.visitClassDeclaration (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:83:60)
at JSONPopulator.visit (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer/jsonpopulator.js:56:25)
at AssetDeclaration.accept (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/introspect/classdeclaration.js:65:24)
at Serializer.fromJSON (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/serializer.js:160:26)
at ensureConnected.then (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-connector-composer/lib/businessnetworkconnector.js:558:43)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
Unhandled error for request POST /api/Offer: Error: error trying invoke chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: Invalid or missing identifier for Type Offer in namespace org.acme.vehicle.auction)
at _initializeChannel.then.then.then.then.catch (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:806:34)
```

Comment: 0
down vote
 

its difficult to know what your local environment / setup is without any info. Can you post your OS version, npm, node and docker, and python versions please?

Also, (may not be related but) it seems you installed this demo as 'root'? We advocate Composer is not installed using root as it can cause npm issues. You should install Composer (ie installing the demo) using a designated, non-root user. There can be issues (eg, on Linux with permissions to write/update node directories located in system directories like /usr/local). You may already be aware.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for posting your local install version info. Its strange you cannot submit a second bid via REST API call, something is amiss  - but do note that your npm version (that was used to install your composer environment and demo setup locally) is unsupported and would not have built properly. See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/installing/development-tools.html for supported version information.

I therefore suggest to uninstall Composer globally `npm uninstall -g composer-cli composer-rest-server generator-hyperledger-composer` - then downgrade your npm environment to a supported version - like npm 3.10.5. Then follow the [link to install](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/installing/development-tools.html) as per above. Also a new install will install v0.9.2 and you should get the matching docker images by downloading fabric-scripts.zip as per the instructions above (these are Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 GA containers to go with the v0.9.2 install environment). Once that is done, we can see if the problem persists in your local environment when you re-install the car auction demo. And correct - Composer must be installed as a non-root user.

Comment: OS version = Ubuntu 16.04
Python version = 2.7.12
npm version=5.1.0
node veriosn=6.11.0
composer version=v0.9.1
docker version= 17.06

I have tried using root user and non-root user. In either case only when I submit bid offer transaction from composer playground connected to fabric works but when I submit bid offer after first transaction it fails with above mentioned error.

Comment: For screen shots on the error and post rest request refer this chat.  https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=tmfue2bYxSaJE7bsd